# Subquery not excluding items from main query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have the following SQL query to exclude employees from 'Post Closing' dept. But I am still getting people in Post-Closing Dept. The `not exists` doesn't seem to be working.

```
select concat(ltrim(rtrim(FirstName)), ' ',ltrim(rtrim(LastName))) Employee
from employeelist t1
where Department_Desc like  '%Closing' or Department_Desc like '%Funding' 
and (Position like 'A1%' or position like 'A2%')
and not exists(select concat(ltrim(rtrim(FirstName)), ' ',ltrim(rtrim(LastName))) Employee
               from employeelist t2 
               where  t1.Employee_Code = t2.Employee_Code
               and t2.Department_Desc in ('Post Closing' ))
```

Any help in resolving this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: `Post Closing` is not the same as `Post-Closing`

Answer (score 1):

Because of operator precedence you get all rows where

```
department_desc LIKE '%Closing'
```

or

```
department_desc LIKE '%Funding'
AND ... -- the rest of the WHERE clause
```

And as `'Post Closing'` is like `'%Closing'` the records with `'Post Closing'` are in the result.

You seem to want

```
WHERE (department_desc LIKE '%Closing'
       OR department_desc LIKE '%Funding')
      AND ...
```

i.e. let the `OR` in the expression on the department descriptions take precedence over the following `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the parentheses.  I would recommend that you write the query as:

```
where (Department_Desc like '%Closing' or
       Department_Desc like '%Funding' 
      ) and
     Position like 'A[12]%' and
     not exists (select 1
                 from employeelist t2 
                 where t1.Employee_Code = t2.Employee_Code and
                       t2.Department_Desc in ('Post Closing' )
                )
```

In addition to fixing the parentheses, there are two changes:

1. This uses SQL Servers support for (limited) character classes in `LIKE` patterns to simplify the comparison for `Position`.
2. The `select` for `exists` is simplified to "1".  `Exists` only checks if a row is returned; the value doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with escape character.

```
and t2.Department_Desc LIKE ('%Post_Closing%' ))
```